# ASP.NET configuration tool won't let me configure "Security" settings

Tags: asp.net

Good day!

I'm trying to get a local membership database setup from my .NET 4.0 (Visual Studio 2010) ASP.NET web app.

I do this:

1) File->New->Project->"ASP.NET Web Application"

2) Compile the application.

3) Open "ASP.NET Configuration Tool," click on "Security" tab.

I get this:

```
There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid
server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the
role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page
where you can choose a new data store. 

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Could not load type 'WebApplication3.Global'.
```

Here is my web.config file:

```
 <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="WebApplication3" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="WebApplication3"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="WebApplication3" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="WebApplication3" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I kind of expected it to "just work" out of the box. I made some changes to the web.config based on some other stackoverflow posts (enable `roleManager`, etc.).

There is no .mdf file in my App_Data directory either. If I try to add one, I get this:

[image]

I just want to use a dedicated, local, database for my authentication information.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have [SQLEXPRESS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx) installed?

Comment: `The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Could not load type 'WebApplication3.Global'.`  Sounds like there was a problem loading the global.asax file, perhaps?

Comment: RE: Petar - No, I don't have SQLEXPRESS installed. Do need to have that running? Does that mean I have to have it running on the production server too? I *thought* you could just have a local MDF to read/write data to. I'm looking for the easiest way to manage authentication (Login control, etc.) and this looked like it might fit the bill.

Comment: IIRC, you need SQLEXPRESS to run mdf files.

Comment: You need some kind of data access technology installed.  It doesn't have to be Sql Server Express.  A better choice if you only want a local database might be Sql Server LocalDB (which still says express, but it's not really) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SQL Server Compact edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx). It's aimed at being small and easier to distribute with your asp.net web application.

Comment: See my comment above, SQL Server LocalDB is a better chance than CE in most cases, as it provides all the standard functionality of SQL Server without the client/server aspect.  SQL CE has a subset of functionality.

Comment: I agree that'll be true in many cases @MystereMan but if he only needs the db to hold authentication information, then wouldn't LocalDB be too much? LocalDb (32Mb download/160 MB on disk) quite a bit larger than SQL CE (2.5/12). There's a good comparision here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving this error try to check this things.

**1**. Make sure your database engine is configured to accept remote connections
• Start > All Programs > SQL Server "version" > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Surface Area Configuration
• Click on Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections
• Select the instance that is having a problem > Database Engine > Remote Connections
• Enable local and remote connections
• Restart instance

**2**. Check the SQL Server service account
• If you are not using a domain account as a service account (for example if you are using NETWORK SERVICE), you may want to switch this first before proceeding

**3**. If you are using a named SQL Server instance, make sure you are using that instance name in your connection strings in your ASweb P.NET application

• Usually the format needed to specify the database server is machinename\instancename
• Check your connection string as well

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SampleConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=machinename\instancename;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=60;Connect Timeout=30″ providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**4**.You may need to create an exception on the firewall for the SQL Server instance and port you are using
• Start > Run > Firewall.cpl
• Click on exceptions tab
• Add the sqlservr.exe (typically located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.x\MSSQL\Bin, check your installs for the actual folder path), and port (default is 1433)
• Check your connection string as well

**5**.If you are using a named SQL Server instance, make sure you are using that instance name in your connection strings

**6**.Check SQLBrowser; check that it is running. You may also need to create an exception in your firewall for SQLBrowser.

**7**.Check that you have connectivity to the SQL Server.

Note what you are using to connect: machine name, domain name or IP address? Use this when checking connectivity. For example if you are using myserver
• Start > Run > cmd
•netstat -ano| findstr 1433
•telnet myserver 1433
•ping -a myserver

Check what ports are IP addresses are being returned.

If you still can’t get any connection, you may want to create a SQL account on the server, a corresponding SQL user on the database in question, and just use this username/password combo in your web application.
**reference**:[7 things to check to resolve  “A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server…”](http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331)

Answer (score 0):

Membership Provider you are using is dated. You want to use new [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx).

Either way, you need to install at least [SQL Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) in order to test it.